# How to filter points in plot_mapbox() using crosstalk widget?

Tags: r, plotly, mapbox, crosstalk

I'm trying to create a map visualization in plotly using mapbox (`plotly::plot_mapbox()`), where the points in the map belong to different geographical districts ("comunas") and the user can choose a geographical district in a drop-down widget created by `crosstalk::filter_select()`.

The expected behavior is that, when a geographical district is selected in the widget, it should trigger a filter in the map, which should only show the points that belong to the selected district.

However, I'm unable to make it work (I'm following the instructions presented [here](https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html)). The code that I wrote successfully creates 1) the map and 2) the filtering widget, but the components don't interact/talk to each other, i.e. when I select a district in the drop-down, there is no filtering effect in the map, it keeps showing all the points, not only those who belong to the selected district.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I make this work as intended?

Below is a reproducible example with a subset of the original data (it requires a Mapbox token to run):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)

data <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~Comuna,         ~Latitude,        ~Longitude, ~id,
    "Alhué", -34.0227777777778, -71.0994444444444,  1L,
    "Alhué", -34.0958333333333,          -71.1825,  2L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.3827777777778, -71.4163888888889,  1L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.3827777777778, -71.4163888888889,  2L,
    "Alhué", -34.0227777777778, -71.0994444444444,  3L,
    "Alto Biobío", -37.8830555555556, -71.6280555555555,  1L,
    "Alto Biobío", -37.8830555555556, -71.6280555555555,  2L,
    "Alhué", -33.4430555555556, -70.7488888888889,  4L,
    "Alhué",           -33.445,          -70.6475,  5L,
    "Alhué",           -33.445,          -70.6475,  6L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.4136111111111, -71.4827777777778,  3L,
    "Alto Biobío", -37.8866666666667,            -71.63,  3L,
    "Alto Biobío", -38.0883333333333, -71.3458333333333,  4L,
    "Alto Biobío", -38.0913888888889, -71.4113888888889,  5L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.3827777777778, -71.4163888888889,  4L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.3827777777778, -71.4163888888889,  5L
  )

plot_example <- 
  data %>%
  plot_mapbox(
    lat = ~ Latitude,
    lon = ~ Longitude,
    text = ~ Comuna,
    mode = "markers",
    hoverinfo = "text") %>%  
  layout(mapbox = list(
    style = "dark",
    center = list(
      lat = ~ median(Latitude),
      lon = ~ median(Longitude)
    ),
    zoom = 6
  )) %>% 
  group_by(Comuna)

shared_key_cells <- highlight_key(data, ~Comuna)

bscols(
  filter_select("Comuna", "Comuna", shared_key_cells, ~Comuna,
                multiple = FALSE),
  plot_example
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `plot_example` needs to use the shared data. This should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)

data <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~Comuna,         ~Latitude,        ~Longitude, ~id,
    "Alhué", -34.0227777777778, -71.0994444444444,  1L,
    "Alhué", -34.0958333333333,          -71.1825,  2L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.3827777777778, -71.4163888888889,  1L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.3827777777778, -71.4163888888889,  2L,
    "Alhué", -34.0227777777778, -71.0994444444444,  3L,
    "Alto Biobío", -37.8830555555556, -71.6280555555555,  1L,
    "Alto Biobío", -37.8830555555556, -71.6280555555555,  2L,
    "Alhué", -33.4430555555556, -70.7488888888889,  4L,
    "Alhué",           -33.445,          -70.6475,  5L,
    "Alhué",           -33.445,          -70.6475,  6L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.4136111111111, -71.4827777777778,  3L,
    "Alto Biobío", -37.8866666666667,            -71.63,  3L,
    "Alto Biobío", -38.0883333333333, -71.3458333333333,  4L,
    "Alto Biobío", -38.0913888888889, -71.4113888888889,  5L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.3827777777778, -71.4163888888889,  4L,
    "Algarrobo", -33.3827777777778, -71.4163888888889,  5L
  )

shared_key_cells <- highlight_key(data, ~Comuna)

plot_example <- 
  shared_key_cells %>%
  plot_mapbox(
    lat = ~ Latitude,
    lon = ~ Longitude,
    text = ~ Comuna,
    mode = "markers",
    hoverinfo = "text") %>%  
  layout(mapbox = list(
    style = "dark",
    center = list(
      lat = ~ median(Latitude),
      lon = ~ median(Longitude)
    ),
    zoom = 6
  )) %>% 
  group_by(Comuna)


bscols(
  filter_select("Comuna", "Comuna", shared_key_cells, ~Comuna,
                multiple = FALSE),
  plot_example
)
```